# How to have multiple discount amount in single coupon code in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

Single coupon code but multiple discount amount depending on the country provided for shipping. i.e I need multiple discount amount with multiple country. Like i need discount amount $5 for Australia and $10 for Canada. How can this be implemented? Any help

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can give this type of discount with the use of cart price rule Action tab condition.
[image]

I hope this will helpful for You...

Comment: But this would do only with one discount amount. I need multiple discount amount with multiple country. Like i need discount amount $5 for Australia and $10 for Canada.

Comment: You must create different rules to achieve this functionality ...and the coupon code will not same for different rules